# Работа с объектом в JS

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь. Есть задачка - Вывести день недели на русском или английском языке. День задается номером в неделе (от 1 до 7). Должна быть возможность указывать язык. По умолчанию - русский.

Мое решение:

```js
var week = {
 'RU1': 'Понедельник',
 'RU2': 'Вторник',
 'RU3': 'Середа',
 'RU4': 'Четверг',
 'RU5': 'Пятница',
 'RU6': 'Суббота',
 'RU7': 'Воскресенье',

 'EN1': 'Monday',
 'EN2': 'Tuesday',
 'EN3': 'Wednesday',
 'EN4': 'Thursday',
 'EN5': 'Friday',
 'EN6': 'Saturday',
 'EN7': 'Sunday'
};

function showDay(week, setLang, setNumberDay) {

 var answer = setLang + setNumberDay;

 for(var key in week) {
  if (answer == key) {
      console.log(week[key]);
     }
 }
}

showDay(week, 'EN', 5);
```

Но нужно это сделать как объект со свойствами и методами. Помогите

Comment: цикл не нужен, просто выводите `if (week[answer]) { console.log(week[answer]); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var week = {
  RU: [
    undefined,
    'Понедельник',
    'Вторник',
    'Среда',
    'Четверг',
    'Пятница',
    'Суббота',
    'Воскресенье'
  ],
  EN: [
    undefined,
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
  ],

  showDay: function(aLanguage, aDayIndex) {
    if (this[aLanguage]) {
      if (this[aLanguage][aDayIndex]) {
        console.log(this[aLanguage][aDayIndex]); 
      } else {
        console.log("unknown day index"); 
      }
    } else {
      console.log("unknown language"); 
    }
  }  
};

week.showDay('EN', 5);
week.showDay('RU', 3);
week.showDay('FR', 3);
week.showDay('RU', 100);
```